# UNION не выводит все столбцы

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Хочу создать оконную функцию которая будет показывать проблемы с объектами в базе.
Планировалось выводить фильмы, актеров, компании
Я написал

```
CREATE VIEW static
AS (
  (SELECT title FROM title t
    LEFT JOIN cast_info ci on t.id=ci.movie_id
    WHERE kind_id=1 and ci.role_id !=1 and ci.role_id !=2)
 UNION ALL
  (SELECT  name FROM name n
    LEFT JOIN cast_info ci ON n.id=ci.person_id
    WHERE ci.person_id IS NULL)
 UNION ALL
  (SELECT name FROM company_name cm
    LEFT JOIN movie_companies mc ON cm.id=mc.company_id
    WHERE mc.company_id IS NULL)
 )
```

У меня не появляются ошибки, но выводится только 1 столбец title, как это исправить?

Comment: `SELECT title, NULL AS name FROM ... UNIOIN ALL SELECT NULL, name FROM ....` - так будет 2 столбца (но результат Вам все равно вряд ли понравится)

Comment: @ArchDemon я написал что я хочу вывести. Зачем заходить, что тут язвить.

Comment: @Yaant спасибо.

Comment: *я написал что я хочу вывести* Надо было (впрочем, если проблема ещё не решена - то до сих пор надо) показать на примере. Ты показал, как ты пытался (неудачно для тебя) решить задачу, а вот о том, что и как надо вывести - ни полслова. *Зачем заходить, что тут язвить.* Вообще-то он сообщил то, что Вы должны были сами увидеть, но не увидели.

Comment: @Akina Я не прав получается. Хочу вывести первый столбец который соответствует первому запросу `SELECT title`, 2 столбец в котором будет 2 запрос  `SELECT  name FROM name ` и 3 запрос в третьем столбце. И что бы это все выводилось одновременно. Запросы надо объединить через UNION . Я написал про Представления `CREATE VIEW` на случай если оно как то повлияет на синтаксис запроса. Вопрос по прежнему открыт. Если решение как предложил @Yaant то, как вывести что бы не было : 1 столбец (NULL)  2 столбец (Значение) 3 столбец (NULL).

Comment: Почитайте в документации что и с чем объединяет UNION.

Comment: Покажите пример исходных данных и требуемого результата (форматированной табличкой на 2-3 записи) - причём в варианте, когда запросы возвращают разные результаты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предполагаю, что надо нечто типа

```sql
CREATE VIEW static
AS (
WITH
cte1 AS (SELECT title, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY title) rn 
         FROM title t
         LEFT JOIN cast_info ci on t.id=ci.movie_id
         WHERE kind_id=1 and ci.role_id !=1 and ci.role_id !=2),
cte2 AS (SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) rn
         FROM name n
         LEFT JOIN cast_info ci ON n.id=ci.person_id
         WHERE ci.person_id IS NULL),
cte3 AS (SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) rn
         FROM company_name cm
         LEFT JOIN movie_companies mc ON cm.id=mc.company_id
         WHERE mc.company_id IS NULL)
SELECT cte1.title film_title, cte2.name actor_name, cte3.name company_name
FROM cte1
FULL JOIN cte2 USING (rn)
FULL JOIN cte3 USING (rn)
);
```

Правда, пока не понимаю, что есть "проблемы с объектами в базе"...

---

Ещё один вариант интерпретации задания:

```sql
CREATE VIEW static
AS (SELECT title entity, 'film' type
    FROM title t
    LEFT JOIN cast_info ci on t.id=ci.movie_id
    WHERE kind_id=1 and ci.role_id !=1 and ci.role_id !=2
   UNION ALL
    SELECT  name, 'actor'
    FROM name n
    LEFT JOIN cast_info ci ON n.id=ci.person_id
    WHERE ci.person_id IS NULL
   UNION ALL
    SELECT name, 'company'
    FROM company_name cm
    LEFT JOIN movie_companies mc ON cm.id=mc.company_id
    WHERE mc.company_id IS NULL
   );
```

Comment: это задание. Первое что обязательно через union надо. По порядку:Я вывожу фильмы без актеров. Название фильма в title, через джойн я выбираю условие. 2 вывод имен актеров которые нигде не снимались, то есть они есть в таблице name но их нет в таблице где написаны роли. 3 компании которые ничего не сняли
| 1 столбец             |2 столбец    |          3 столбец
|--------------------------|------------------|----------------------------|
| Название фильма| Имя Актера |Название компании|

Comment: @Skroubar То есть задача - тупо вывести никак не связанные данные в три столбца? Тогда мой запрос именно это и делает. А если надо непременно к какой-нить заднице прислонить UNION - то используйте на моих CTE показанную Yaant технику, а потом группировка по rn и MAX().

Comment: Создайте представление, которое будет показывать проблемы с объектами в базе. Это будет несколько выборок с полями: имя сущности (фильм, актер, компания), идентификатор объекта в его таблице, текстовое название объекта, комментарий с описанием проблемы. Эти выборки должны быть объединены с помощью UNION. Выборки следующего содержания:` .  Как то так. В любом случае, спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: @Skroubar Ещё вариант добавлен.